Help with audio on Kubuntu 24.04
Earlier today, my sound was working just fine, but ever since I restarted my computer (to install nvidia drivers), my sound does not work. I tried restarting again, but my audio settings say "no output or input devices found".
I read to run ALSAmixer and configure my card, but I get this output:
ALSA lib confmisc.c:855:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'
ALSA lib conf.c:5204:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_inum returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:422:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings
ALSA lib conf.c:5204:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1342:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating name
ALSA lib conf.c:5204:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5727:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib control.c:1570:(snd_ctl_open_noupdate) Invalid CTL default
cannot open mixer: No such file or directory

My headphones are plugged directly into the motherboard, in a port that I know is good and has always worked. I have also unplugged them and plugged them back in several times.
